# Android RxJava2 multiple EditText validation

Tags: android, rx-java2

I need to validate 7 fields before make rest call. Each validation is single observable that throws an error if string does not match rules. In `onError` method I manage on whitch field to display error message and the text of that message. The problem in that I dont know how to check all fields in that way in zip, for example, dont stoping another observables when some of them throw an error, and in zip check if there was at least one error to prevent rest call.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'd try to describe issue as clear as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onErrorReturn()` operator in order to return a specific item will be emitted when it encounters an error.

For example, if we have two observables and the first one fails and the second one doesn't, you have something like this, and the log message will be printed.

```
Observable.zip(Observable.error(new Throwable())
                        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> Result.fail()), 
                Observable.just(new Result("body")),
                (BiFunction<Object, Result, Object>) (o, result) -> result)
                .subscribe(o -> Log.d("test","both observables completed."));
```